# How is hotness calculated on the Hot Network Questions page?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

Hovering over a link on the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) page gives a tool tip of the form:

> This question has been arbitrarily awarded X hotness points

I presume the points calculation is not actually arbitrary, so how is it calculated?

Comment: Age is definitely a factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The formula is described here: [How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page)

> The core of the formula (without the site-based degrading or traffic scaling) is:
>
> ```
> (MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
> -------------------------------------------------
>          MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
> ```

As noted there, some sites have an additional adjustment made to their score to account for differences in voting patterns and answer rate, and when multiple questions from the same site are returned each additional question is penalized to prevent a single site from overwhelming the list. We make regular tweaks to these modifiers, so you should generally consider the score to be somewhat arbitrary.

Note that this differs from the algorithm used on *site-specific* hot pages, which is described here: [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose you have to watch out for sneaky question hotness optimisation tricks too!