# Why do hot questions have negative votes?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but most of the questions in the "hot" list have negative votes and will most likely close soon. Perhaps this is by design if you look at it in terms of hot meaning the questions are burning because of the low score. If it doesn't show up like this for you, here's a screenshot of the list:[image: Hot questions image]. How does the hot question list get populated? Is it supposed to be like this? I am under the impression that hot means popular questions right now, not low-score questions like the ones shown above.

Edit: the formula appears to be this: `(log(qViews)*4) + ((numOfAns * qScore)/5) + sum(answerScores)`

Also a related question is here: [How is hotness calculated on the hot network questions page?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252029/how-is-hotness-calculated-on-the-hot-network-questions-page)

Answer (score 1):

Views and answers also factor in to the hotness algorithm. Those negatively voted question have lots of views and most have a few answers. The downvotes should remove them from the hot list soon, though.

Comment: Is 30 views a lot of views?

Comment: @Milo In a short period of time, yes. Most of the negative score questions were also modified or answered in the past few minutes.

Comment: Well according to the hotness equation in the linked post, the last question should have a score of 0. Therefore it should not appear on the list at all. And others have a negative score.

Comment: @Milo That formula is for the "Hot Network Questions" list in the sidebar. You're looking at the site specific Hot list, which uses a different formula. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/1288

Comment: How often is that tab updated?

Comment: @Milo I don't know.