# How did this question end up at the top of the hot list

Tags: support, hot-questions

This was the second result in the hot questions tab [When would you ever want a GetHashCode() to collide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170437/when-would-you-ever-want-a-gethashcode-to-collide)

[image]

Hotness formula: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252030/1026459

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
     MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```

At this time, the hotness is approximately

```
3 * -1 / 5 + 1
--------------     =  (-0.5) / 12.2860350665 = -0.04069661182
   6 ^ 1.4
```

Although, that is the network formula (realized after calculation). The original hotness formula as described by Atwood here: [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) is

```
 (log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
 --------------------------------------------------------
 ((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

Meaning that this post has a score of

```
 log(51)*4 + (2*-1)/5 + 3         1.7075701761*4 + 2.6
 -----------------------------  = -------------------- = 9.4 / 1.58 = 5.9557
 ( 1.55 - (.55-.167)/2 ) ^ 1.5     1.58339571069
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here? I feel like this question should not have ended up in the hot list. Not only is it on hold, but it has a negative vote count.

Comment: Does the hot list get recalculated on every vote? That is, could you have seen a cached hot list, calculated with old scores, but displaying the latest votes? It could have been downvoted while in the hot list.

Comment: @Douglas - That did occur to me, there is definitely a lot of caching going on, and I am sure calculating the hotness of every question every second is probably not realistic. Hopefully someone who knows more about why this question was on the list can educate me on this specific example :)

Comment: ATM there are 5 downvoted questions in the top 7 hot questions, very curious

Comment: @CDspace - Just checked (http://i.imgur.com/s2Qq05Z.png) , and that is rather bad. I mean, the first on in the list is "Why does 0 % 3 equal 0?".

Comment: Regardless of quality, my first two 'hot' questions don't even seem very hot http://i.stack.imgur.com/My6T0.png