# The "Hot Questions" list at Stack Overflow seems a little... questionable

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

This is not to be confused with the hot *network* questions list.

I decided to look at the ["Hot" list selection at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) in order to perhaps answer a question. You know, in the rare case they are actually on topic.

No luck. Instead I found this absolute gem: [How do I initialize these arrays in the default constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624688/how-do-i-initialize-these-arrays-in-the-default-constructor)

> I don’t know where to start. How do I create this class?
>
> You will create 3 classes: DeckAndDiscard, Player, and Golf. Write the declaration of these classes each in a file of their own based on the following specifications. You cannot omit any of the attributes or methods given in these classes. You can add some if you like.

It goes on to list a through h of requirements, and to be honest I would have rather seen a spam post with a phone number and a promise.

This question was at 32 views after an hour of being posted, and was at -3 votes with 3 close votes at the time I saw it on the list.

Perhaps it is time to simply shut this list down.

It has had problems for a long time ([2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267951/1026459), [2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330228/hot-questions-are-not-that-hot-currently)), and it doesn't seem to have made any progress.

Comment: Question is now deleted, perhaps as a result of your question.

Comment: A question which was in the process of being *burnt* to the ground was in a list of "hot" questions - makes sense.

Comment: Looks like you can't even access the "Hot" questions if you're a member of a Team (you only see "Stack Overflow Recently Active Questions" instead) :)

Comment: There's probably some overlap (or at least ambiguity) between Active, Hot, Interesting and Frequent. Although I only ever use Newest.

Comment: @Dukeling I'd also be interested in how these questions are decided on.

Comment: Another [Hot Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627512/how-to-convert-n-bits-to-listlistbool-in-c-sharp) got burned.

Comment: @AndrewT. That is just a section title mistake, when you follow the list in the top post, you get to the Hot questions page as indicated by the `<title>` in your browser, and the contents of the list

Comment: @Ferrybig true, the list shows the hot questions, but there's no filter chooser to get to there except from manually hacking the URL :)

Comment: Does "Hot" imply "Good" though? I think not.

Comment: @Dukeling `POST IS HOT AND MELT` ?

Comment: @Sweeper - It is supposed to, yes. The math used is aimed at measuring the fastest (hottest) growth for posts.

Comment: @JohnDvorak - The post was deleted as a result of it being terrible, and in no relation to this question. It was closed as I wrote this prior to submitting, and deleted just after. Admittedly one of the delete votes was mine, however, this question is not about this one exact question which was easily worthy of deletion; instead, this is about a list purporting to show the best questions which is in fact showing some of the worst content out there.