# What decides which hot network topics are displayed on my page sidebar?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, sidebar

I can't count the number of times that I've been looking for a question that I can helpfully contribute an answer toward or an answer to something I'm working on and ended up reading about [why cyclists land rear wheel first](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32676/what-is-the-purpose-of-landing-on-the-rear-tire) or about [the advantages of fixed wing over swing wing setups in aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-an-oblique-wing-over-a-swing-wing). I'll be honest, it is interesting to know what I need to do if I have [accidentally added too much water to my ciabatta mix](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60070/i-added-more-water-to-my-ciabatta-dough-by-accident) or [how I can effectively liquefy my enemies](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21908/how-can-i-liquefy-my-enemies) (that one was particularly interesting). It's impressive to see such a diverse range of topics being covered in the stack exchange network (I already appreciate the number of different sites available).

My questions is, is there any personalised/activity based logic behind the links that I am being shown for the other networks, is it random or is it the same for everyone (i.e. it really does show everyone on Stack Overflow the same 'hot' network questions?

I think the last option is unlikely, as if there really are 51,000 people on the site at any given time (as according to the stats on the 10 million questions page) then SE would effectively be declaring a DDOS attack on those particular questions from it's own users.

I appreciate that probably only a tiny proportion of people on the site will click the links, especially simultaneously, but it still seems like a bad idea to me regardless. I've also seen apparently 'hot' questions that appear to have had very little interest which seems strange considering [the formula that's used to determine hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page).

So, does my behaviour of clicking a topic tell SE that I am interested in baking ciabatta, or (more worryingly) that between working on my websites I research how I can turn my enemies into puddles of mush? Or is interest in other networks (unlike interests/tags in my main network) disregarded as irrelevant?

If the links are becoming more personalised, I fear that my productively will steadily decline until it reaches a point where I forget what I'm supposed to do, stare blankly at completely unrelated questions while proudly changing my job title from Online Developer to Head of Potatoes.

The only saving grace is that it takes more than a couple of clicks to join another network...

**UPDATE:**

This is not a duplicate of '[how are hot network topics calculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252029/how-is-hotness-calculated-on-the-hot-network-questions-page)' as I already know that, my question is regarding *what decides which hot network topics are displayed on MY page sidebar*, not how they are calculated.

This has been answered [at another meta site (MSE)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993).

Comment: It is my understanding that the hot questions are the same for everyone.  Thus, in addition to "the meta effect," we also have "the hot question effect" where certain posts receive a disproportionate number of votes (even some very low-quality or off-topic posts).

Comment: I don't know if that's a good thing or not... It's good that I'm more likely to keep my job (as obviously I have no self control to stop myself getting distracted like most people!) but it's bad because, well, as you say - the misleading "hot question effect".

Comment: All of the above, not necessarily in that order.

Comment: [big list of 100 questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) is the same for everyone. Questions from this list are [randomly shuffled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993/165773) to your sidebar

Comment: Ah-ha! Thanks @gnat. Also thanks for correcting my spelling in the title - can't believe I missed that!

Comment: you're welcome. FWIW few days ago Programmers moderators deleted several questions that were used to entertain the hot questions audience: [Recent Trouble With Popularity](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7525/31260) (not that I complain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Big list" of 100 hot questions ([located here](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)) is the same for everyone, but what you see at your sidebar is not like that.

Different users in different times see different selections from that list, randomly shuffled to their sidebar. Details and reasoning for this are explained in [this answer at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222993/165773):

> This is a recent change which resulted in a 30% increase in engagement. All of this engagement came from repeated clicks.

Currently, the hot questions list is basically a list of 100 or so questions from the whole network. All we are doing is randomizing the list of 100 before we pull some off the top, instead of pulling the top X every time...

---

On a historical note, in the past it was indeed so that displayed questions were the same for everyone (that's what above quote means referring "recent change"). And the effect sometimes was, as you correctly guessed, like that of DDoS attack, especially because the system is designed to amplify this with something like a "snowball effect".

- <sup>Since you mentioned that you understand how hotness is [calculated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252029), you can easily figure how it went. Question entering hot list gained anomalous amount of upvotes and answers, which pushed it higher in the list, which led to even more upvotes and answers and so on... If you are interested in more details on how it was back then, refer old MSE discussion: [Don't let questions stick to the top of the hot questions list forever](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99077/165773). "That's how fake popularity makes shit stick to the ceiling and helps to keep it there..."</sup>

As explained in [another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302991/839601), exposure in hot list is still troublesome but randomized shuffling made it much *much* less prominent than it was before.

It is also interesting to note that Stack Overflow questions have sort of additional protection against negative effects you asked about. As opposed to hot questions from other sites, these have a [special adjustment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250154/165773) which strongly pushes them out of the hot list after first 7 hours.

Answer (score 7):

Hot Network Questions basically *is* a self-DDoS. Smaller sites often have a lot of trouble managing the votes (and not infrequently answers) from clueless 101-rep visitors from the rest of the network on such questions. It's especially bad on sites that a) share little genuine expertise with SO's crowd (we're the number 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 source of traffic, far as I can tell) and b) have enticing question titles. (Fortunately, the sites that are the best — or worst — at coming up with such titles are mostly geek-dominated: Arqade and maybe PCG.)

If you can't tell, I don't think much of the feature, and have it hidden on all SE sites via AdBlock Latitude.

Comment: I also hide HNQ.  I do read the hot questions from the Android app, but I deliberately refrain from voting on them.

Comment: I will add votes and other contributes to questions on the HNQ list, but I made a conscious effort to do so within community guidelines for the particular site. I know not a lot of people make that effort, but I try to do my part. If a question is popular enough to be on that list, _and is a quality question or answer_, why not help reward the poster with a bunch of rep? They clearly made a very positive contribution.