# Adding popularity/hotness metric in the post itself

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**I would like a way to tell if a post I'm looking at is "trending".**

When looking at a post the view count is basically how you determine how popular the post is/was, but for aging posts it can be hard to determine if this post **IS** popular or **WAS** popular. I think that info is sometimes useful to have. To my knowledge, currently there is no way to tell.

**Two opposite sides of the spectrum for the sake of example:**

1. a classic post that is still highly relevant gets  consistent new views every month -- that tells me when I look at it, I'm not the only one still asking even if the post is old

vs.

2. a post with many views that is no longer looked at, perhaps a good post on an aging technology that fewer and fewer people care about -- that me tells I'm wondering about a question that others have collectively moved on from.

**Possible Implementation:** *View count in last 30 days.*

Not sure if this is the best way to show trending, but it's the first that came to mind.

*Would others find something like this useful as well?? Is there already a way to see this that I don't know about?*

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments, "hotness" is this metric for trendiness and it already exists. The question is: **Can we see hotness from the post itself? Is that a useful feature?**

Comment: Very related [Hotness score for HNQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252029/how-is-hotness-calculated-on-the-hot-network-questions-page)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Is there a way to see hotness for a given post from the post itself?

Comment: Not really.  You'd have to calculate it yourself.  But it is something that currently exists so that can help you refine your feature-request.  Otherwise your implementation is really lacking and non-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Because we're programmers:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Post Hotness Score
// @namespace   NoNamespacePlease
// @description Adds the post hotness score to the question title
// @include        /^https?:\/\/\w*.?(stackoverflow)\.com\/(questions).*/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  var rawtimestamp = $("#question td.owner span.relativetime").attr("title");
  var qAge = Math.floor((Date.now() - Date.parse(rawtimestamp)) / 36e5);
  qAge = Math.max(qAge + 1, 6);
  qAge = Math.pow(qAge, 1.4);

  var aCount = parseInt($("span[itemprop='answerCount']").text());
  if (isNaN(aCount)) aCount = 0;

  var qScore = parseInt($("#question span.vote-count-post").text());

  var aScore = 0;
  $("#answers span.vote-count-post").each(function() {
    aScore += Number($(this).text());
  });

  var hotness = (((Math.min(aCount, 10) * qScore) / 5 + aScore) / (qAge));
  $("#question-header h1").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hotness: " + hotness);

});
```

Produces:

[image: Screenshot]

Uses the formula from [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252030/5240004).  Questions with multiple pages of answers won't have the correct hotness value, as this only parses the first page.

Everyone, feel free to make edits to improve this or fix any bugs that you find. (I'm not a JavaScript/jQuery expert. As if that's not obvious by the monstrosity above.)

Comment: as far as I can tell you forgot to account for special site-specific adjustment [roughly explained here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246925/165773). It divides the hotness score of Stack Overflow questions by about 5 - you probably can get more accurate value of divisor by picking a random SO question that is currently in [hot list](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), looking at it "arbitrary awarded" points reported in tooltip and comparing against the value you calculated